# Visual studio 2015, remove event handler and error of design form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

in visual Studio 2015 when deleted event of control code, form will not be displayed and show Error linked to EventHandler of control in design form. But it is not on Visual Studio 2010. Is it behavior VS 2015, like the behavior of VS 2010?

Comment: what exactly is the error that pops out?

Comment: You need to remove the event subscription from the form's designer code

Comment: open your designer file and remove the event registration entry.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the event from the controls will not delete the event code itself, but if you are talking about a window application and you deleted the event handler in the code you must also delete it in the `*.designer.cs` file.

This behaviour exists both in VS 2010 and in VS 2015.

Comment: yes, but I mean that unwanted Handler that are involved. if you remember in 2005 it was erased and corrected automatically. in 2010 you did not have clear EventHandler moment and could do at compile time doing it. But in 2015 you must delete the moment EventHandler from designer

Comment: @bahramshamloo You are correct. That behaviour was changed after VS 2005. Newer versions do not delete it automatically, and as a guideline, do not interfere with code changes when removing UI elements. Your question was about 2010, so I assumed that was what you were refering to.

Comment: In fact, my question was how to behave Visual studio. Because in VS2010 despite a bad eventhandler in the designer but showing the form in design mode was not in trouble. Of course, the simplest form possible. for example: When you a dataSet that is bind to a dataGridView if one of the columns of change dataSet, you are no longer able to see the form in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the reason with Vs2010 or Vs 2015 , you must delete faulty code from `designer.cs`